# SQL Server install - MSI install error - Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x80080005?

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server-2008, msi

I don't know why but i'm very frustrated today, I always failed in installing any kind of SQL Server express edition on my XP SP3 laptop:

2005 into 2008 Standard and Advanced 32 bit all will always failed with the following error attached.

can anyone suggest to me what to do next please ?

FYI: here's my MSI version Windows ® Installer. V 4.5.6001.22159

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup
------------------------------

The following error has occurred:

SQL Server Setup has encountered an error when running a Windows Installer file.

Windows Installer error message: The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if you are running Windows in safe mode, or if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed. Contact your support personnel for assistance.

Windows Installer file: W:\SQL2008ENT\SW_DVD5_SQL_Svr_Enterprise_Edtn_2008_English_MLF_X14-89207\x86\setup\SqlSupport.msi
Windows Installer log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20110411_103331\SqlSupport_Cpu32_1_ComponentUpdate.log

Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22&EvtType=0x5D9A8C61

------------------------------
BUTTONS:
&Retry
Cancel
------------------------------
```

and here's the log file content:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 11/04/2011  10:35:03  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 4.05.6001.00  Calling process: W:\SQL2008ENT\SW_DVD5_SQL_Svr_Enterprise_Edtn_2008_English_MLF_X14-89207\x86\setup100.exe ===
MSI (c) (44:A0) [10:35:03:798]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (44:A0) [10:35:03:798]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (44:A0) [10:35:03:798]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: W:\SQL2008ENT\SW_DVD5_SQL_Svr_Enterprise_Edtn_2008_English_MLF_X14-89207\x86\setup\SqlSupport.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (44:A0) [10:35:03:798]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (44:A0) [10:35:03:798]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (44:A0) [10:35:33:845]: Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x80080005

MSI (c) (44:A0) [10:35:33:845]: Failed to connect to server.
MSI (c) (44:A0) [10:35:33:845]: MainEngineThread is returning 1601
=== Verbose logging stopped: 11/04/2011  10:35:33 ===
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Albert

Comment: What does the log file given in the message say?

Comment: Richard, I've updated with the log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps below and it works:

```
Log on to your computer as an administrator.
Click Start, and then click Run.
In the Open box, type cmd, and then click OK.
At the command prompt, typemsiexec.exe /unregister, and then press ENTER.
Type msiexec /regserver, and then press ENTER.
```

From:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315353 (resolution)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315346 (workarounds)

Answer (score 1):

Error `0x80080005` is CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE, and the initial description is "The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed."

Supposition: the SQL Server installer couldn't set up communication with the MSI service to perform the install.

I would start by getting the latest WinXP MSI upgrade and running that (even if not a new configuration) to try and reset its configuration (not just as a service, but in Component Services—ie. DCOM—also).

Otherwise you're likely looking at at least a repair if not a fresh install.

Comment: well I have updated or installed the latest Windows Installer v 4.5 from 3.0 but it is still the same error message ?